# Commit only property changes on root of repo, not files

Tags: svn, version-control

I have an SVN repository with uncommitted changes to files. There is also a change in the svn:externals property on the root folder.

How do I commit the property changes, WITHOUT committing the changes to the files themselves?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

In order to commit only the explicit paths specified on the command line use the `--depth empty` option e.g. in the directory with the newly modified externals property:

```
$svn commit --depth empty . -m "Modify svn externals definition only."
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to change the property you can do it against the repository right away, instead of against your working copy.

For example:

```
svn propset svn:externals "test http://yourhost.com/svn/trunk/module/test/src" --revprop -r HEAD http://yourhost.com/svn/trunk/module
```

See the [SVN book on manipulating properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.manip)

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain what to do when you forget to add the commit message, and you have a property change hanging out in the middle of a large number of file changes.

Comment: Isn't this a property on the revision? Instead of in the directory?

Also, it depends on having a `pre-revprop-change` hook